# Is there a Transparent, Non-Magnetic Conductor?

Tags: material-science

I am looking for a transparent (visual wavelength: 390 to 750 nm), non-magnetic (not attracted by a magnet) electrical conductor that could be used for a physics demonstration. Is there such a substance? If yes, is there a cheap one?

Answer (score 5):

A tank of water for ac current or a tank of water+salt for dc current would do the job.

Answer (score 4):

indium-tin oxide (ITO), through which you are reading this text quite now ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indium_tin_oxide )